# How to pass parameter on change function JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

in my application, a select can be change manually (by clicking) or automatically (by calling "change" function).
I want to pass string argument to my method "change" but i don't know if it's possible.
My try so far :

```
$(this).val(val).change({mystr="byloop"});
```

And the listenner :

```
$("select").change(function(e, mystr) {
    //do stuff
})
```

Thanks for help, and sorry for my low english level

Comment: Use trigger method `$('select').trigger('change', {mystr: 'hello'});`  and `$("select").change(function(e, data) { data.mystr });`

Comment: Thanks man, it work for me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's not duplicate because data need to be send each time you trigger and not when you add handler.